# Spring MVC multiple selection using backend bean

Tags: spring-mvc

I am creating a web application in Spring MVC using Spring form capabilities.When I submit jsp form,i am getting data as String array from multiple selection box on controller,and then stores in database.When user edit records how can i display selected option items in multiple selection box.

This map is used to fill multiple selection box.

```
Map mp = new HashMap();
mp.put("111", "test1");
mp.put("112", "test2");
mp.put("113", "test3");
mp.put("114", "test4");
mv.addObject("cat", mp);
```

this map is user seleted option list ,fetched from db.

```
Map selMap = new HashMap();
selMap.put("111", "test1");
selMap.put("114", "test4");
mv.addObject("selcat", selMap);
```

How can i show test1 and test4 selected on edit page in same order.
I need result in this format.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will give you example using Spring annotations:
This will work as your referenceData for form.

```
@ModelAttribute("cat")
public List<String> referenceData(){
    Map mp = new HashMap();
    mp.put("111", "test1");
    mp.put("112", "test2");
    mp.put("113", "test3");
    mp.put("114", "test4");

    return mp;
}
```

Now you can select the data values in the multiple drop down as

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap map){
        StudentCommand command =new StudentCommand();
        Map selMap = new HashMap();
        selMap.put("111", "test1");
        selMap.put("114", "test4");
        command.setCat(selMap);
        map.addAttribute("command", command);
        return "studentregistration";
    }
```

**JSP**

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="cat" items="${cat}" itemLabel="cat" itemValue="something" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Shoaib for your quick reply,it's not showing selected items.